# Will our new sandbox cause problems with review audits?

Tags: support, reviewing, sandbox, review-audits

For those of us with 500+ & -2000 reputation, there are two review queues open: First Posts, and Late Answers. The LA I;m not worried about, but sometimes, in the FP queue, we have questions that show up with 0 votes, say something like 'asked 2 hours ago', etc, like a real post. If the question is good, and you upvote it/NAN, you pass the audit. If it is good and you DV/flag, you fail.

But with our new sandbox, new riddle questions that didn't go through the sandbox are DVed (sometimes), flagged, VTCed, and closed! This means tha if you DV and flag it in the queue, when actually the riddle was from before the sandbox, you will fail! So what'll happen now?

Disclaimer: I'm not 100% sure that flagging fails the audit. I think it does, though.

Disclaimer 2: This has **not** happened to me.... yet.

Comment: failing only means you can't review for (I think) a day

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil I failed one once. Nothing happened. But if you fail enough, you can get banned.

Comment: Subsequent audit failures will result in longer bans (2, 7 then 30 days). There's a simple solution though: just open the question in a separate tab. You'll quickly see if it is an audit or not.

Comment: I'm not sure opening in another tab to game the audit system is really in the spirit of the audit system...

Comment: @Sconibulus Well, it shows that you're paying attention enough to spot an audit, at least.

Comment: @Sconibulus, As Emrakul says, it shows you're paying attention, which is the main goal of an audit. It is okay to sometimes disagree with the majority, for example, what I might find a borderline answer and would click "Edit", you might find unsalvagable and click "Recommend Deletion" (in the Low Quality queue)

Comment: What is the review audit?

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/review-audits/info).

Comment: @Sconibulus If people don't open the post in a separate tab when reviewing *anyway*, then they probably aren't reviewing properly. Context is everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a serious issue. While it's plausible that one might fail an audit for this reason, failing a review audit here or there won't hurt you long-term.

On the rare off-chance you're rate limited for failing too many recent audits, you've almost definitely messed up way more than one.

On the even slimmer off chance that exclusively failing these audits results in a review ban, just flag one of your posts, ping us in chat, or even ask here on meta, and we'll unban.